# Django many to many relationsip update field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have two models many to many relationships, I am trying to update a field by subtraction two values from the two models and save the changes to the db.

```
class LeaveBalance(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True,)
    Leave_current_balance= models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Year=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    def __unicode__(self):
             return  self.Year
```

```html
class NewLeave(models.Model):
 user=models.ForeignKey(User,default='',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        leave_balance=models.ManyToManyField(Leave_Balance)
        leave=(
        ('annual','annual'),
        ('sick','sick'),

     )

   Leave_type=models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=leave,blank=False,default='')

        Total_working_days=models.FloatField(null=True,  blank=False)
        DirAuth=(
            ('Pending','Pending'),
            ('Approved','Approved'),
            ('Rejected','Rejected'),
        )

     Director_Authorization_Status=models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=DirAuth,default='Pending',blank=False)
 Date_Authorized=models.DateField(null=True,blank=False)
 Authorized_by_Director=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='',blank=False)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return  self.Leave_type
```

here is my form, when a leave is submitted the director is notified by email. the director can login to the system to approve the leave using the form. once the leave is approved, I want to adjust the Leave_current_balance.

```html
class DirectorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=NewLeave
        fields=('Director_Authorization_Status','Authorized_by_Director','Date_Authorized',)
        widgets={
            'Date_Authorized':DateInput()
        }
```

This is the function that allows the director to approve the leave which throws the error: u'Leave_current_balance'

```html
def unitDirectorForm(request,id):

    if request.method=='POST':

        getstaffid=NewLeave.objects.get(id=id)
        form = DirectorForm(request.POST, instance=getstaffid)
        if form.is_valid():
            getstaffid = form.save(commit=False)
            getstaffid.save()

            total_days = getstaffid.Total_working_days
            current_balance = getstaffid.user.leave_balance.Leave_current_balance
            diff_balance = current_balance - total_days
            current_balance = diff_balance
            current_balance=form.fields['Leave_current_balance']
            current_balance.save()
            getstaffid.leave_balance.add(current_balance)

            return HttpResponse('You have successfuly Authorise the leave')

    else:
        #getstaffid=NewLeave.objects.get(id=id)
        form=DirectorForm()
        #c_balance=Leave_Balance.objects.get()
        balance_form = leavebbalanceForm()

    return render(request,'managerauthorisedform.html',{'form':form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get this working in another way too. For example:

```
def on_balance(user_id):
    id = user_id
    c_balance = LeaveBalance.objects.get(user=id)
    current_balance = c_balance.Leave_current_balance
    t_days = NewLeave.objects.get(user=id)
    total_days = t_days.Total_working_days
    current_balance = current_balance - total_days
    balance = LeaveBalance.objects.get(user=id)
    balance.leave_balance = current_balance
    balance.save()
```

And the above does not cause combined expression error.

Or just a bit simpler:

```
def on_balance(user_id):
    id = user_id
    c_balance = LeaveBalance.objects.get(user=id)
    current_balance = c_balance.Leave_current_balance
    t_days = NewLeave.objects.get(user=id)
    total_days = t_days.Total_working_days
    current_balance = current_balance - total_days
    c_balance.leave_balance = current_balance
    c_balance.save()
```

**UPDATE - restructuring the models and views**

So the above code works if it's used in an appropriate model/form/view structure, but instead I would suggest you to restructure the whole thing starting from your models. I give you a simple working example (I tested this and works):

**My app name** is in this example: `Myusers1` , so where ever you see that, you can change that name to your app name if needed.

**So the Models:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.db.models import F
from django.urls import reverse

class Director(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default = '', null = True, verbose_name = 'Name of Director')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Staff(models.Model):

    TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('REGULAR', 'Regular'),
    ('MANAGER', 'Manager'),
    ('FRESH', 'Fresh'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default = '', null = True, unique=True, verbose_name = 'Name of staff member')
    birthdate = models.DateField(blank = True, verbose_name = 'Birth date')
    department = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default = '', null = True, verbose_name = 'Department')
    # department could also be a choice field from another table
    type = models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices = TYPE_CHOICES, verbose_name = 'Position Type', null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class LeaveBalance(models.Model):

    staff = models.ForeignKey(Staff, to_field='name', on_delete = models.CASCADE, primary_key = False)
    Leave_current_balance = models.FloatField(null = True, blank = True, default = '')
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, verbose_name = 'Last Updated date and time')

    def __unicode__(self):
             return  self.Leave_current_balance

class NewLeave(models.Model):

    all_staff = Staff.objects.values()
    STAFF_CHOICES = [(d['name'], d['name']) for d in all_staff]

    staff = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices = STAFF_CHOICES)
    leave_days_to_approve_now = models.FloatField(null = True,  blank = False, default = 5.0, verbose_name = 'Leave days for approval now')

    LEAVE_CHOICES=(
    ('annual','annual'),
    ('sick','sick'),
    )

    Leave_type = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices = LEAVE_CHOICES, blank = False, default = '', verbose_name = 'Type of leave')
    Total_working_days = models.FloatField(null = True,  blank = False, default = 200.0)

    APPROVAL_STATUS_CHOICES=(
        ('Pending','Pending'),
        ('Approved','Approved'),
        ('Rejected','Rejected'),
    )

    Director_Authorization_Status = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices = APPROVAL_STATUS_CHOICES, default = 'Pending', blank = False)
    Date_Authorized = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, verbose_name = 'date and time of Authorization')

    all_directors = Director.objects.values()
    DIRECTOR_CHOICES = [(d['name'], d['name']) for d in all_directors]
    Authorized_by_Director = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices = DIRECTOR_CHOICES, default = '', blank = False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return  self.Leave_type

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        pass
        # return reverse('newleave-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk}) # this should be worked out too

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        staff_name = self.staff
        this_staff = Staff.objects.get(name=staff_name)
        name = this_staff.name
        minus_value = self.leave_days_to_approve_now
        if (self.Director_Authorization_Status == 'Approved'):
            LeaveBalance.objects.filter(staff = name).update(Leave_current_balance=F('Leave_current_balance') - minus_value)
            return super(NewLeave, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return super(NewLeave, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**In the above,** you can see that I created a **Director** and **Staff** Model in which you can set as many staff and directors as you want in the Admin back-end. I created the staff Model because maybe not all of the staff will be users, so I think it is just a bit better to keep them separately in the DB from Users.

**Important:** first create the Director and Staff Models then migrate immediately since the other two tables will depend on them. Then you can create the other two Models.

I also do not think that in the **LeaveBalance Model** you should keep more things than what I put there. I think Year field for example redundant, since you can always filter by the date and date range in you want in the database.

**Then the views** (I used simple views only directly from the Models). With using these view classes you do not have to create Forms since it is automatically created from the Models and you can handle them with different functions/methods as Forms in the Views and in the Model classes.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse, HttpRequest
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views import View
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic import ListView, TemplateView
from django.template import loader
from .models import NewLeave
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView, CreateView, DeleteView, UpdateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class NewLeaveCreate(CreateView):
    model = NewLeave
    fields = '__all__'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        super().form_valid(form)
        auth_status = form.cleaned_data['Director_Authorization_Status']
        if (auth_status == 'Approved'):
            return redirect('Myusers1:success_page')
        elif (auth_status == 'Pending'):
            return redirect('Myusers1:pending_success')
        else:
            return redirect('Myusers1:rejected_success')

class NewLeaveUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = NewLeave
    fields = '__all__'

class NewLeaveDelete(DeleteView):
    model = NewLeave
    success_url = reverse_lazy('newleave-list')

class NewLeaveDetail(DetailView):
    model = NewLeave
    template_name = 'myusers1/newleave_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'newleave'
    queryset = NewLeave.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(NewLeaveDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['leave_details'] = NewLeave.objects.filter(pk=pk)
            return context

class Success(TemplateView):
    template_name = "authorizationsuccess.html"

class pending_success(TemplateView):
    template_name = "pendingsuccess.html"

class rejected_success(TemplateView):
    template_name = "rejectedsuccess.html"
```

Then in urls.py I defined the required urls:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views
from . import models

app_name = 'Myusers1'

urlpatterns = [
path('newleave/add/', views.NewLeaveCreate.as_view(), name='newleave-add'),
path('newleave/<int:pk>/', views.NewLeaveUpdate.as_view(), name='newleave-update'),
path('newleave/<int:pk>/delete/', views.NewLeaveDelete.as_view(), name='newleave-delete'),
# path('newleave/add/<int:pk>/', views.NewLeaveDetail.as_view(), name='newleave-detail'),
path('newleave/add/success/', views.Success.as_view(), name='success_page'),
path('newleave/add/pendingleaves/', views.pending_success.as_view(), name='pending_success'),
path('newleave/add/rejectedleaves/', views.rejected_success.as_view(), name='rejected_success'),
]
```

I have not worked out all of the url paths.

And the **templates** like the `newleave_form.html`

```
{% extends 'myusers1/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class"container">
  <div class="col col-lg-2">
    <h2>New Leave Form</h2>
    <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form }} 
      <button type="submit">Authorize</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**And there should be** at least 3 different redirect template when a they **submit** a NewLeave form, `authorized, pending, and rejected` templates. I just give here the simple authorized success template:

```
{% extends 'myusers1/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Thank you! The authorization of leave was successful</h2>

  <div class="col-xs-12 .col-md-8"><li><a href="{% url 'Myusers1:index' %}"> Back to Home </a> </li></div>
{% endblock %}
```

Do not forget **to migrate** and then register the models **in the admin.py**. Then you should create some staff in the database and few directors to try the above. I hope that the above can give you some direction to accomplish what you are up to with your project. With this I just wanted to give you a very simple example. (You have to create all of the other necessary templates and views).

If you create a new app for trying the above then in your project main urls.py file you should reference (include) your app urls like this with adding one extra line to your project' urls.py file. Then all of your new app urls has to be defined in your app's urls.py file:

This is how your main project's urls.py looks like then:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('myusers1/', include('Myusers1.urls')),
    # so in your case:
    path('myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
]
```

(you have to change the `Myusers1` to your app name,)

And of course we could do a lot of other things with the **Model Manager in Django:** https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/

Comment: Thanks, I have a function that allows the director to approve the leave. As soon as the leave is approved I want to adjust c_balance is. Is there a way to accomplish that.

Comment: this throws the error LeaveBalance matching query does not exist

Comment: @sum - you get the error because in LeaveBalance table there is no record yet for that user (user_id). Your model structure is a bit confused. But if you set records and you tries to save the forms then the code should be a bit fine tuned. To do that we should see what the hell exactly you are doing. Which means, we should see where the director arrives to this view from. He is choosing a user and then he tries to input days and then he tries to submit or what? So your model and form and view should be reformulated. This code works if it’s used correctly.

Comment: @sum - leave_balance field is for example unneccesary in your second Model(NewLeave model), since you want to just update the field current_leave_balance at every submission.

Comment: @Zollie-I have updated my models and added my forms and views which is throwing the error  u'Leave_current_balance'

Comment: traceback: current_balance  

17.0

diff_balance  

17.0

form  

<DirectorForm bound=True, valid=True, fields=(Director_Authorization_Status;Authorized_by_Director;Date_Authorized)>

getstaffid  

<NewLeave: annual>

id  

u'10'

request  

<WSGIRequest: POST '/unitDirectorForm/10/'>

total_days  

1.0

Comment: @sum - I’ll check the whole thing a bit later and try to serve you some good, step by step, solution and structure on this with updating my answer customized on your case exactly. If it’s not too late, by tomorrow sometime.

Comment: Thanks, very much appreciated

Comment: I think it is throwing error because Leave_current_balance is from the model Leave_Balance. which is not part of the form, in the line current_balance=form.fields['Leave_current_balance'].

Comment: @sum — have you checked my update? You should try it in a new app in your project.

Comment: @zollie- thankyou i will try it out tonight and let you know.

Comment: its throwing an error django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: myapp_staff, when i try to migrate. my app name is myapp, it there are any relationship between Staff and NewLeave?

Comment: @sum — first, you have to just create two models: Director and Staff, then migrate immediately since the next two models will depend on them. So when you created the first two Models, then migrate, then create the two other tables, LeaveBalance and NewLeave and that way it will not throw error. You have to keep the dependencies always in mind when you create models and migrate. Sorry I should have noticed these in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, i am having issues with my URL error Page not found (404). I place my url under myapp urls.py. should i place it place all the urls under the my main projects url?

Comment: @sum - I updated my answer about how you have to include (reference) your new app's urls in your main projects urls.py file. You have to add just one extra line in your main project urls.py file for that.

Comment: i was actually doing when but its throwing  the error  URL error Page not found (404)

Comment: @sum -- have you created index (home) page for your myapp? Your app index page should be reached at: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/` Is it working now? You have to check all of the urls and html templates that you created them. Also in the error message you have to see what is missing and you have to check those missing things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188514/discussion-between-zollie-and-sum).

Comment: thanks for you help. I still want to make the staffs and directors users of the system because they will be using the system to apply for leave and check their leave balances online thanks again for your time. I will try to figure out how to do that

Comment: @sum - it’s not a problem, the structure can be built like that too. I just wanted to give you an example that if the models are built a bit cleaner, then the whole thing can work. You have to just figure out carefully the relationships of the models then everything will work for you. Take care!

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `refresh_from_db` on balance. like `balance.refresh_from_db()` to get the updated values from database.

Comment: @ Mohit Solanki thanks, after calling the refresh_from_db() now i am getting an error   

'CombinedExpression' object has no attribute 'leave_balance'